# Django Channel Update with Sending Messages

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have been trying to update the chat room whenever a specific model gets updated. The websocket connections work well and the Django signals work well also.

However, when I try to send a specific message to the group, it would not work. I made sure the function (in this case, "schedule_update") gets activated by putting a debugger and sure enough, it gets activated.

Below is the channels function in question:

```
class GroupShareDataApi(WebsocketConsumer):

    # permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def connect(self):
        self.channel_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['channelId']
        self.room_group_name = self.channel_id

        # Join channel group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_id
        )

        print(self.room_group_name)

        self.accept()
        return self.send(json.dumps({"message": "CONNECTED!"}))
.
.
.
.
.
.

    async def send_message(self, event):
        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': "hello"
        }))

    @receiver(post_save, sender=VacationData)
    def schedule_update(instance, sender, **kwargs):
        group_name = "5fcf479d889fa60001000201"
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
      
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            group_name,
            {
                "type": "send_message",
                "text": "what's up?"
            },
        )
```

And this is the Web Socket Testing... which shows nothing other than the message it shows when connected:

By the way, the channel_id (or channelId) is "5fcf479d889fa60001000201". Since the group name is also the channel id, there is no way I mispointed the group. How do I properly send messages and update the group chat?

[image]

Comment: show your send_message function

Comment: ```    async def send_message(self, event):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': "hello"
        }))```

Comment: Are you certain the group name you defined is the same as the one assigned earlier? The channel_id is new per new connection so you shouldn't be using it. Better use something else that is known in both sections of the code

Comment: Okay, I will try to do what you told me to do! Thanks!